# Selenium C# - I'm unable to find an element on this page using any of the locators

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

This was just a random script I made to complete a quiz but I can't seem to access the final element. I want to select the element, click the element and then send some text to the element.

I have tried to access the input box by class name, CssSelector and by XPath.

The website is https://www.16personalities.com/free-personality-test

Here are the XPaths I have tried:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'email-wrapper')]
//div[contains(@placeholder, 'your@email.com')]
//div[@class="row request-info-wrapper"]
//*[@id='request - email']"
```

[image: An image to make things clearer :)]

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm new to the framework and would very much like to know what I'm not understanding about locators! Thank you!

EDIT:

I can't seem to target this element or any of its children:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have selected wrong `tag DIV`.Try this following `Xpath`. All should work.

```
"//input[@id='request-email']"
```

Or

```
"//input[@name='email']"
```

Or

```
"//input[@placeholder='your@email.com']"
```

Comment: Hey, I tried all 3 of those but my terminal still returns false and throws and exception :/ Here's my code after implementing the last suggestion you made:                 // Inputting and submitting an email to receive results
                IWebElement inputEmail = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='your@email.com']"));

                Console.WriteLine(inputEmail.Displayed);

Comment: Yes, strangely it doesn't throw an exception unless I try to click the element or send keys to the element but at the same time the displayed property returns false. Here is the error:    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()

Comment: I can share the github link with you if that would be more useful?

Comment: Ok Share then?If possibble can you please post

Comment: Like 84 is where I'm trying to locate the element

Comment: well why you need to click on the input field.You can pass sendkeys with value.Have you tried other all  3 types of Xpath which I have provided?

Comment: Yeah, I pasted them in as you wrote them and the bool returns false and I still get that error :(

Comment: Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <input id="request-email" placeholder="your@email.com" name="email" value="" type="email" style="overflow: hidden; width: 14.4762%; right: 44.4286px;"> is not clickable at point (1387, 811). Other element would receive the click: <button class="btn btn-lg btn-action" id="request-send" type="button" style="right: 0px;">...</button>

Comment: Ahhhh, okay. I understand. I will try to send keys with the value property. I have never done that before.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the element had to be active before I could send keys. It works!

Comment: Great.Happy Learning

Answer (score 1):

Your field has a (presently) unique ID of "request-email".

Thus you can simply use, as a CSS selector,

```
('#request-email')
```

Then, in you can simply tell Selenium to hit ENTER to save your data.  Let me know if you need help doing that.

Comment: Hey, I tried but the program throws an exception, it can't seem to find the element. Here is my code:                 // Inputting and submitting an email to receive results
                IWebElement inputEmail = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#request-email"));

                Console.WriteLine(inputEmail.Displayed);

Comment: The console.writeline returns false too :/

Comment: Thank you C.Peck! I thought the element had to be clicked before I could sendkeys. I made such a simple mistake!!!

Comment: Well, now you know! :)